# Cannot make changes into Postgres config file by script

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a script for changing settings in PostgreSQL and then reloading config

I need to change by script, the parameter value from something which was before, to "all" ;

I've tried the following:

```
/xxxxx/../../bin/psql -U postgres -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement TO 'all';
```

seems it doesn't work

After, I need to restart the service, where I will have to make
su - postgres
And run following command

```
/xxxxx/../../bin/pg_ctl reload -D /xxxx/folder_of_postgres_conf file
```

Any ideas on how to write the parameter change command?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a valid Postgre**s** error message. But your first command is missing a `'` at the end

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name its missing a `"`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `pg_reload_conf()` and pass both SQL statements as a "heredoc" so that you don't need to worry about embedding quotes in quotes:

```sh
/xxxxx/../../bin/psql -U postgres << EOF
  ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement TO 'all';
  select pg_reload_conf();
EOF
```